# Customised Spinner

Tags: android

I am making a project where I need to make a customised spinner where each option consists of an image view and a text box. I am new in Android. Any idea? A sample code will be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do like use of `Custom Adapter`

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />

    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/weekofday"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
     android:text="Sunday"
     android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomSpinner.java**

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Activity {

    String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    Integer[] image = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(CustomSpinner.this, R.layout.test, DayOfWeek,image)); 
    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] objects, Integer[] image) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
            label.setText(DayOfWeek[position]);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(image[position]);
            return row;
        }    
    }
}
```

Place some images in your drawable folders. Have a look at [Here](http://venkateshsblog-android.blogspot.in/2011/04/custom-spinner-with-text-and-icons.html) Also [this](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=android%20text%20with%20image%20in%20spinner&oq=android%20text%20with%20image%20in%20spinner&gs_l=hp.3..33i29.54.84410.0.84764.52.44.0.1.1.3.801.14076.2-20j6j6j4j2.38.0...0.0...1c.JrhSLCZ_HwA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9b3ab69b02d40f6&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=785)

Comment: Thank you. Somehow when I searched in Stack Overflow by "custom spinner" nothing actually showed up.

Comment: Are you sure that your code is working, Because as per your answer Row.xml is row for spinner but in your adapter your inflate R.layout.test

Comment: By the way,what is the Layout test?

Comment: Fine now, don't take on negative sense but minor mistake leads to errors.

Comment: @syamantak The layout which is going to be inflated into spinner for contents with  `ImageView` and `TextView`